# Vue component not displaying data in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

**`index.html`:**

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>

    <div id="counter">
        {{ counter }}
    </div>
      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

**`index.js`:**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
})

const Counter = {
    data() {
        return {
            counter: 0
        }
    }
}
  
Vue.createApp(Counter).mount('#counter')
```

and the output is:

```
Hello Vue!
{{ counter }}
```

Why is my code for `counter` not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the syntax for two separate versions of Vue.

`new Vue` is v2, `Vue.createApp` is v3.

For your code to work with v2:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})

const Counter = new Vue({
  el: '#counter',
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>

<div id="counter">
  {{ counter }}
</div>
```

---

For your code to work with v3:

```js
var app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
  }
})

const Counter = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      counter: 0
    }
  }
})

app.mount('#app');
Counter.mount('#counter');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
</div>

<div id="counter">
  {{ counter }}
</div>
```